# Docker, How can I locate the image files after pulling

Tags: docker

After pulling image, for example **ubuntu**, how can I locate the image file on local disk.

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
```

Will the image work if I copy the image file to another machine?

OS: macOS

Comment: It's stored somewhere inside /var/lib/docker, and copying it is discouraged. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, since the pulling process is slow, so I wanna pull the image and copy the image file to another machine, it 's `docker pull quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames:0.20.2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Aim is to copy any image from one machine to other.

execute the following in the machine where the images are present

```
docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>
```

Then copy your image files to the other machine using any regular file transfer tools such as cp or scp. Then execute the following command there

```
docker load -i <path to image tar file>
```